# Can I use Google Cloud Pub/Sub across different Google Cloud projects?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

Let's say I have project A, B and C in Google Cloud with several cloud functions in each one.

I want to setup a Pub/Sub in project C so the functions in A and B can subscribe to.

Is this possible? Do I need to setup some kind of service account with custom permissions?

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know the PubSub topic must be in the same project as the Cloud Functions that it triggers. But you could publish to that topic *from* other projects.

Comment: To send push notifications to functions in other projects I think its possible as it is a simple HTTP request from the Pub/Sub server. But to publish from other functions is something that I'm not sure about

Comment: I cannot answer for Google Cloud Functions specifically, but I have a PubSub in one project that I access (both to publish and subscribe) from apps on Google Cloud Kubernetes Engine in a different project. `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` simply has to point to the certificate of a service account with access to the PubSub in the correct project.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen could you post your comment as an answer? Thank you.

Comment: I'm actually not sure I am correct. @ZackK seems to indicate that it *is* possible to call PubSub across projects, which is a better answer for what OP is asking.

Answer (score 13):

In the subscribing project on the IAM page, add a new member with the Pub/Sub Publisher role, the new member name is the serviceaccount-email of from the publishing project.
Then create a cloud function in the publishing project and assign the same service-account in the bottom of the page(under more) to the function.

Here's a node example for a cloud function:

```
const PubSub = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');
const pubsub = new PubSub();
const topic = pubsub.topic('projects/subscribing-project-name/topics/topic-to- 
publish-to');
const publisher = topic.publisher();

exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
const customAttributes = {
message: 'Hello'
};
publisher.publish(Buffer.from("Hello from another project"), customAttributes, 
(err) => {
if (err) {
  res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, error: err.message }));
  return;
}
res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({ success: true, message: "Message sent to 
pubsub topic" }));
});
};
```

Comment: Is it possible the other way? Like The consumer project listening to the events in source/producer project? This way we can use the events directly generated within producer project and avoid any custom code.

Answer (score 5):

As you mentioned in the comment, you can **subscribe** to the topic from another Cloud Functions if you set a [push subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#create_a_push_subscription).

To [**publish** to a Pub/Sub topic from another project](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control#cross-project) you should grant the  right permissions for it's service account in the destination project.

Comment: I'm setting up a push-subscription in project A towards a cloud function,  subscribing to a topic in project B. Project B gave me some rights for me to be able to subscribe to their topic. It's working fine, but even if project B removes all my access-rights, I can still listen to the topic. So in this way project B is not in control of their own topic if they wish to terminate a subscription. Is there a solution where project B is in full control and also removes any hard coupling between the projects?